# Tool/Service for Ethereum Smart Contract Analytics

Tags: analytics, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am looking for app or online service that could provide detailed analytical information about Ethereum smart contract usage. With transactions count, number of users, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to get insights about your smart contract activity.

You can check https://etherscan.io/ and find a list of transactions. It can be very helpful if you need to view individual transactions. Etherscan shows a number of transactions and other useful information.

If Etherscan is not enough for you, there are other apps. You can check https://scout.cool/ and https://analyther.com. Analyther works with any smart contract and gives you detailed charts of transactions, events, active users, etc. It makes reports like this: [image: USDC transactions report]

Answer (score 2):

[Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io) provides smart contract metrics & analytics. They also create aggregated data from the raw blockchain data. So they provide everything previously mentioned and more!

- Live contract event monitoring: 
  [image: Live contract event monitoring]

  - Historical contract events graph
  - Adoption & Usage:
    [image]
    For example, this is [Cryptokitties](https://amberdata.io/addresses/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/metrics
    ). Looks like there has been a major spike in the number of inbound transactions to this contract in the last 24 hours.
  - Detailed lists of transactions to and from the contract
  - Graph showing transactions with the contract (light blue dots are EOAs, and the dark blue square are smart contracts.)
    [image]

It's pretty neat! I am most excited about [the API](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference/reference-getting-started). There's so much data to explore.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://www.stateofthedapps.com

DApp is an acronym for Decentralized application, which encompasses a frontend and a smart contract as the backend.

The site lists the most used DApps on various platforms. It provides graphs like user, transaction and development activity over time. It also links to the relevant transactions on the blockchain and specifies details like creators and software license, if available.